# How do I fix "TypeError: vue_p5__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.createCanvas is not a function" when trying to use p5.js inside a nested vue component?

Tags: vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, p5.js

I am currently trying to create this app (https://repl.it/@prophetorpheus/collaborative-sketch) in vue.js as a vue component of my App.vue file.

When i am trying to call the setup function inside my vue component ( i called it Whiteboard.vue) i get this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: vue_p5__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.createCanvas is not a function"

found in

---> <Whiteboard> at src/components/Whiteboard.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
```

Am i doing something fundamentally wrong or is there a problem due to the difference in versions between my approach and the linked application?

These are the relevant parts of my code ( as far as i am able to judge them to be relevant to the problem :D), ( i changed the firebase config Data ):

```
<template>
      <div>
        <button @click="execute">hit me</button>
      </div>
    </template>



    <script>
    import Vue from "vue";
    import firebase from "firebase";
    import p5 from "p5";
    import * as vuep5 from "vue-p5";

    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      apiKey: "------------",
      authDomain: "--------------",
      databaseURL: "--------------",
      projectId: "-------------",
      storageBucket: "----------------",
      messagingSenderId: "----------------"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    var pointsData = firebase.database().ref();
    var points = [];

    function setup() {
      var canvas = vuep5.createCanvas(1500, 1500);
      vuep5.background(255);
      vuep5.fill(0);
      pointsData.on("child_added", function(point) {
        points.push(point.val());
      });
      canvas.mousePressed(drawPoint);

      canvas.mouseMoved(function() {
        if (mouseIsPressed) {
          drawPoint();
        }
      });
    }

    function draw() {
      background(255);
      for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        var point = points[i];
        ellipse(point.x, point.y, 5, 5);
      }
    }

    function drawPoint() {
      pointsData.push({
        x: mouseX,
        y: mouseY
      });
      return false;
    }

    export default {
      name: "Whiteboard",
      data() {
        return {};
      },
      methods: {
        execute() {
          setup();
          draw();
          drawPoint();
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
```

My goal is to create a working real time collaboration whiteboard-drawing app
with vue, firebase's real-time database & p5. 
Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that you need to use instance mode or some sort of wrapper function from the vue-p5 package.